# For loops to open a file that has to variable in the name

Tags: php, arrays, json, for-loop

Hello I may have a really dumb question.

What I have got is code that writes a json file, in the file name it automatically adds to variable that is incrementing a number. I want to make the code that opens the file and writes the data to the web page. Opening the files that are `filename(1)(1).json` works, but no other file opens.

This is the code to create the file.

```
$Array = array("User Index" => $UniqueIndex,"User Name" => $UniqueUserName,"Submition Index" => $SubmitionCount,"Time & Date" => $TimeDate,"Submition" => $_POST["submition"]);
$ArrayWrite = fopen("forumdata/forumsubmition/ForumSubmition($UniqueIndex)($SubmitionCount).json", "w");
fwrite($ArrayWrite, json_encode($Array));
fclose($ArrayWrite);
```

This is the code that tries to open the file.

```
for ($Count = 0; $Count <= $blarg; $Count += 1)    
    for ($Count2 =0; $Count2 <= $blarg2; $Count2 += 1)
        if (file_exists("forumdata/forumsubmition/ForumSubmition($Count2)($Count).json"))
        {
            do
            {
                $ForumInfo = file_get_contents("forumdata/forumsubmition/ForumSubmition($Count2)($Count).json", "r");
                $ForumInfo2 = json_decode($ForumInfo, true);

                if ($ForumInfo2["Submition"] != null)
                    foreach($ForumInfo2 as $value)
                        echo "$value<br>";
            }
            while (file_exists($ForumInfo));
        }
```

Comment: Please change your variable names. They should at least be camelCased

Comment: You are using the same variable `ForumInfo` for both the **content** and the question if the file exists (`while(file_exists($ForumInfo))`. This won't work as expected. Additionally, where are the curly brackets around the `for` loops?

Comment: @Jan the for loops don't need braces for there's only one statement following - fixed formatting so that it's more clear

Answer (score 0):

Why would you even have the `Do While` loop when you got 2 `for` loops that loops over the files?
Just do this:

```
for ($count = 0; $count <= $blarg; $count += 1)    
    for ($count2 =0; $count2 <= $blarg2; $count2 += 1)
        if (file_exists("forumdata/forumsubmition/ForumSubmition($count2)($count).json"))
        {
                $forumInfo = file_get_contents("forumdata/forumsubmition/ForumSubmition($count2)($count).json", "r");
                $formattedForumInfo = json_decode($forumInfo, true);

                if ($formattedForumInfo["Submition"] != null)
                    foreach($formattedForumInfo as $value)
                        echo "$value<br>";
        }
```

I also formatted your variables to camel cased instead of pascal cased.

The reason you shouldn't juse the do.. while loop is because you already have a second for loop that rounds through all `$blarg2` counts. Then you have a `if` construction that checks if the file exists. That should be enough. No need to check again. Because if it dosn't exist it just jumps over it and goes to the next count in your second `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks that is better code. It is not fixing my main problem The file name creation is set on 2 variables $UniqueIndex  and $SubmitionCount, UniqueIndex is the index number allocated to the user that can be any thing from 1 to ∞ and submitioncount is the index number attached to the text input the user has put in and also can be any thing from 1 to ∞. So i need it to be able to open any file with that combination  ForumSubmition(1 to ∞)(1 to ∞).json this could be very simple but i can't see it.

Comment: Ignore my last comment. It did fix everything I can now move on to the next section of this project i am working on. Thanks

Comment: Great, would be awesome if you marked mine the answer then ;)

Comment: @S-spirit - Still no answer marked :( #AgesAgo